# MUI Select (Multiple Checkbox) - All other buttons in the page are not clickable until closing the dropdown

Tags: select, material-ui, dropdown, multiple-choice

MUI Select (Multiple Checkbox) - All other buttons in the page are not clickable until closing the dropdown

Even in their example page, when I open the dropdown, select item/s , i MUST click outside the dropdown to make all other buttons in the page, to be clickable.

[image]

Any workaround for this one?

Tried to play with the focus but it didn't help

Comment: The MUI Select component renders a [Backdrop](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/backdrop/) component that overlays the entire page and serves as a way to close the Select menu. How do you plan to close the menu if you decide to remove it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the Select component is not clickable or scrollable is because it is based on a popover, which may block user actions. You can use the Popper component instead.

[popper](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popper/): The scroll isn't blocked like with the Popover component. The placement of the popper updates with the available area in the viewport.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.